# Is there a way to tweak my code to prevent my submenus from opening from resizing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, mobile-website

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/jasonhuang24/pen/jOxRNjx).

```
let widthMatch = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1080px)");
let widthMatch2 = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1080px)");
// mm in the function arg is the matchMedia object, passed back into the function
widthMatch.addEventListener('change', function(mm) {
  if (mm.matches) {
    // it matches the media query: that is, min-width is >= 1080px
    if (burgerDivEle.classList.contains('on') && navUlEle.classList.contains('nav-active')) { //bigger than 1080p clean up classes, so the nav bar is in the original state.
      nav.classList.remove("nav-active");
      burger.classList.remove('on');
    } else if (!burgerDivEle.classList.contains('on') && !navUlEle.classList.contains('nav-active'))
      widthMatch2.addEventListener('change', function(mm) { //shrink it back down to 1080p, re-add it, only under the condition that we removed it first.
        if (mm.matches) {
          nav.classList.add("nav-active");
          burger.classList.add('on');
        }
      });
  }

});
```

I can't figure out the logic to prevent my dropdown from automatically opening when I resize the window to my mobile view when I haven't clicked the hamburger.
Bear in my everything else works just fine. It closes when I go bigger and it stays open if you've already clicked the hamburger.

Preferably I'd like to know of a quick fix through JavaScript. I'd like to know if that's possible without having to make a new one from scratch.

Comment: Adding an event listener inside another event listener is usually a code smell.

Comment: Yeah, that's something I'm working on too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own question, it was so simple by adding a placeholder class. Also cleaned up the nested event listener, thanks to the tip.

```
widthMatch.addEventListener('change', function(mm) {
  if (mm.matches) {
    // it matches the media query: that is, min-width is >= 1080px
    if (burgerDivEle.classList.contains('on') && navUlEle.classList.contains('nav-active')) { //bigger than 1080p clean up classes, so the nav bar is in the original state.
      nav.classList.remove("nav-active");
      burger.classList.remove('on');
      nav.classList.add('been-removed')
      burger.classList.add('been-removed')
    }
  }
  });

  widthMatch2.addEventListener('change', function(mm) { //shrink it back down to 1080p, re-add it, only under the condition that we removed it first.
    if (mm.matches) {
      if (burgerDivEle.classList.contains('been-removed') && navUlEle.classList.contains('been-removed')) {
      nav.classList.add("nav-active");
      burger.classList.add('on');
      nav.classList.remove("been-removed");
      burger.classList.remove('been-removed');
    }
    }
  });
```